# jQuery: working with numbers & commas

Tags: jquery, integer

I'm working on a function to update totals on my shopping cart and I'm running into a problem with numbers.

When a quantity is changed I fire the `updateTotals()` function which will update the totals in the cart `<table>`, the problem I'm having is with a number over 1000 that has a comma in it.

For example, `Product 2` is `$5,775,00`, so when I increase the quantity by 1 and run `updateTotals()`, the total that's returned is `11.55` instead of `11,550`.

I'm pulling my hair out at this `parseFloat()`, `parseInt(`), `Number` malarkey because no matter what I've tried I can't get the right result.

```
<tr id="tr-10072229">
    <td><i class="fa fa-trash text-muted remove"></i></a></td>
    <td><input type="number" name="quantity" data-id="10072229" value="1" class="update-qty"></td>
    <td>Product 1</td>
    <td>&#36;<span id="price-10072229">50.00</span></td>
    <td>&#36;<span id="total-10072229">50.00</span></td>
</tr>
<tr id="tr-10044516">
    <td><i class="fa fa-trash text-muted remove"></i></a></td>
    <td><input type="number" name="quantity" data-id="10044516" value="1" class="update-qty"></td>
    <td>Product 2</td>
    <td>&#36;<span id="price-10044516">5,775.00</span></td>
    <td>&#36;<span id="total-10044516">5,775.00</span></td>
</tr>

<script>
    function updateTotals(id,quantity) {

        // update our price and total cols
        var taxrate = 0.08;
        var price   = parseFloat($('#price-' + id).text().replace(',', '.'));
        var ptotal  = (price*quantity);
        $('#total-' + id).text(ptotal.toFixed(2));


        // loop through the table and get the updated totals
        var subtotal = 0;
        var table = $('table tbody');
        table.find('tr').each(function (i, el) {
            // find each <td>
            var $tds = $(this).find('td');

            // total is in a span in the 4th <td>
            total = parseFloat($tds.eq(4).find('span').text().replace(',', '.'));

            // add the totals to get the subtotal
            subtotal += total;
        });

        // print the subtotal
        $('#subtotal').text(subtotal.toFixed(2));

        // multiply subtotal * our tax rate
        var tax = (subtotal*taxrate);

        // print the tax
        $('#tax').text(tax.toFixed(2));

        // add subtotal and tax to get grand total
        var total = (subtotal + tax);

        if(total == 0) {
            // cart is empty: hide the table and show 'empty' message
            $('table#cart').hide();
            $('#cart-content').html('<h4 class="text-danger">There are no items in your cart</h4>');
        } else {
            // print the total
            $('#total').text(total.toFixed(2));
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following line from your code

```
parseFloat($tds.eq(4).find('span').text().replace(',', '.'))
```

Will convert `"5,775.00"` to `"5.775.00"`, which parses to 5.775. You need to *remove* the comma, not replace with a period.

Comment: That was my original code `replace(/,/g, '')`. Doesn't make a difference, I still get 11.55

Comment: Not sure what else is going on, but that is definitely part of the issue. See http://jsfiddle.net/joellee/xhp5g4ja/ for a reduced version of your code.  Replacing ',' with '' produces a total of $11550.00, whereas replacing with '.' produces a total of $11.55. Note that there are no commas in 11555.00 when the total is output, due to how javascript formats numbers when converting to string. But that has nothing to do with removing the commas so you can parse correctly.

Comment: You're correct. I was replacing the comma with a period in TWO places and - because i'm so friggin' burned out - didn't realize it. Your fiddle pointed that out to me and it's now working. Thank you :)